# Simulating key press using bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I try to run gedit from terminal and type some text in a file opened there, but have no success. I try to use `gedit; sleep 2; xte -x display 'key k';` command but this one run gedit only(without typing the k char). Can some one chip in me?

Comment: Sounds like you are asking how to loosen a wheel-nut, when you actually want to fix a puncture. Can you describe what your bigger picture that you are trying to solve is?

Comment: @MatsPetersson I try to write bash automation script for running some apps and simulate user's action (key pressing, mouse moving e.t.c)

Comment: So some sort of test automation setup? Oh, and what is it that "doens't work".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) (no idea what happened to the webpage, here is its [source](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool)) is great for that:

```
xdotool key k
```

And with gedit:

```
gedit & sleep 2; xdotool key k;
```

Comment: I've tried it, but during compiling there is an error appeared. fatal error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory. I use Ubuntu 12.04 32 bits system. How can I fix it?

Comment: Perhaps you need libx11-dev? But somewhere there are binaries (perhaps even in the Ubuntu repository)

Comment: I install it, but i have the same problem for this util. When I use gedit; sleep 2; xdotool key k; command line it runs gedit only(without typing symbols), and only after closing gedit it types k char in terminal. But how can I force this util to type chars into gedit opened file???

Comment: perhaps i should have actually read your question... See the edit